# Is there a way to refactor two classes to share a parent class (split table) without losing data?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have two models, `Account` and `Visitor`. Right now they are entirely separate tables, but I recently realized I will need to query for either object type. In other words, I need a super-class which both share (call it `User`) such that I may query User and receive either an Account or Visitor object.

When I generate the Entity Framework 6 migration, it ends up breaking the database. Specifically:

- The shared columns are removed from the child model
- No parent (`User`) entries are created, thus the entries in `Account` and `Visitor` become invalid
- In the end, the migration fails because the foreign keys created on Account & Visitor are invalid

Right now, the only approach I have is to:

1. export both child tables via a database dump
2. run the first half of the migration (no FKs)
3. manually backfill the data from (1) into the Users class
4. run the second half of the migration (to add FKs)

Is there a more elegant way to achieve a lossless migration?

Comment: I don't see any issue with the task you have but it is hard to suggest anything specific without your code - models, migrations.. Also do you really need to have new table to keep all the data? you can create User table and keep foreign key to both Account and Visitor - one of them will be filled in. Shared columns might be reused in superclass which will not be a separate db entity

Comment: Hm, I was under the impression that if I wanted to query a User and get either a Visitor or Account back (based on the discriminator) I would need to do this migration. You said "do you really need to have a new table?" and then "you can create User table" — which is the new table.

Comment: you missed the part where I am saying "all the data", I am suggesting to have shared table only to access Visitor and Account as navigation properties, not to push all existing data into new table. This might or might not help you in your use case, but again, we don't have code to say that

Comment: Ahh, I see. Well, that would still require the backfill — since the migration will create the new table, but not add data to it, thus making the rest of the migration (where the FKs are added) invalid. In other words, even just adding a `Users` superclass with nothing more than an `Id` property will create an invalid migration that fails to execute :( The migration process thus becomes a pain, requiring (1) migrate (2) backfill (3) migrate.

Comment: Do not tag `entity-framework-core` and `entity-framework-6` unless you really are using these two different ORM, each first released more than a decade apart. If you're using EF Core 6, that's not the EF6 tag; look at  [ef-core] and its  version numbered derivatives

Comment: ... but there is no `ef-core-6.0` derivative, they stop at 3.1 ... I see the usage note now, but that tag is the only tag that mentions entity + framework + 6 in the same tag... which is horribly misleading.

Comment: You could first add the new User entity. Do not change anything about the Visitor and Account tables. After the migration, use SQL statements to populate the User table. Then add the Visitor and Account changes and complete the migrations.

Comment: Depending on the number of (shared) rows and columns, one of the Visitor or Account tables might turn out to be easier to keep. Inherit that class from abstract User, migrate it to TPH (1) and then a second migration (2) which manually adds the other discriminator and imports data from the second table.